# Se puede cambiar el estilo visual de un DataGridView en C# como si se usara CSS en HTML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Mi duda es sencilla, hay alguna forma de cambiar el diseño de un DataGridview?, nada de la forma en que funciona, solo ponerle algun estilo diferente como se puede hacer con CSS en HTML , para que se vea mas "bonito"

Comment: en la sección propiedades cuenta con ciertos parámetros que puedes utilizar, necesitas o quieres más que esos?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo esos parametros son de tipo funcional en su mayoria, quisiera  algo de "estilo" para mejorar la imagen del programa pues la tabla se ve muy "sencilla"

Comment: Puedes encontrar bastante información en la documentación de Microsoft, en concreto, la información para cambiar el formato la encuentras [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/basic-formatting-and-styling-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control). Si te aparece en inglés, recuerda que puedes ver una versión traducida de la página, desactivando la opción donde dice *'Leer en inglés'* en la parte superior derecha de la página.

Comment: Si la aplicación es en Windows Form tendrás que recurrir a librería de terceros por ejemplo una que se usa mucho es material design https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/winforms-material-design-introduction Si la aplicación es WPF ahí si que puedes aplicar estilos al Datagridview o a cualquier otro control.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/WPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa